# Verifying reproducing property of common kernels in RKHS

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider a reproducing kernel Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, whose elements are functions from $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $t \in X$. Since $\mathcal{H}$ is a RHKS, there exists a unique function $K_t \in \mathcal{H}$ (called the representer of $t$) such that $\langle K_t, f \rangle = f(t)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{H}$. (my ultimate goal will be to find concrete examples of $K_t$ and $f$)

We define $K(t, x) := K_t(x) = \langle K_t, K_x \rangle$ to be the reproducing kernel of $\mathcal{H}$.

One popular kernel is the linear kernel $K:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $K(x, y) = x \cdot y$.

Let's take $X = \mathbb{R}$. So if we take $3 \in X$, then $K(3, x) = K_3(x) = 3 \cdot x$ is the representer of $3$ in $\mathcal{H}$.

Thus, $\langle K_3, f \rangle = f(3)$ for any $f \in \mathcal{H}$. Say $f = K_3$, then $\langle K_3, K_3 \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K_3(x) K_3(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 9x^2 dx = 0 \neq 9 = K_3(3) = f(3)$?

Similarly, what if we take $K$ to be the RBF kernel?

I'm certainly misunderstanding something here...any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle 3x,3x\rangle=3x$ doesn't make sense, as the left-hand side is a number and the right-hand side is a function.  Perhaps some of the problem is the notation.

The correct evaluation is $\langle K_3,K_3\rangle =K_3(3) = 9$.

Note that the RKHS in this case is one dimensional, all of its elements being of the form $f(x) = cx =K_c(x)$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$.

I am not familiar with the RBF kernel, but: What is your question about it?

---

**Added**, after edits to the question 2016-07-07 23:09:18Z:

You have made an incorrect assumption about an integral representation of the inner product.  You have defined the kernel function such that, by definition, $\langle K_x,K_y\rangle = xy$.  Furthermore, to elaborate on the remark above, all of your kernel functions are scalar multiples of $K_1$, hence your space is the one dimensional span of $K_1$, i.e., the functions all have the form $x\mapsto cx$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$.  If you would like a representation of your inner product independent of kernel functions, it is $\langle f,g\rangle=f(1)g(1)$.  This is an integral in a way, with counting measure on a one point set.

Comment: Oops, I've edited my question. Now my confusion comes from trying to evaluate $\langle K_3, K_3 \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K_3(x) K_3(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 9x^2 dx = 0 \neq 9$?

Comment: @jonshao: No, that is not the inner product.  The inner product is by definition $\langle K_t,K_x\rangle=tx$.  (And how do you get $0$ for that integral, out of curiosity?)  If you define the kernel, the space can be built from it, in this case leading to the 1-dimensional space mentioned above.  As for a formula for the inner product independent of the kernel definition, it would be $\langle f,g\rangle = f(1)g(1)$.

Comment: I see my mistake now, thanks! (I also now see that integral is totally wrong too)